# pdoexception sqlstate hy000 1044 access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'laravel'

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-migration

- code app/config/database.php. i set database name as laravel.

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laravel',
        'username'  => 'forge',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

[image: that image from cmd]

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right file? It looks like the command has tried to login without a user name.

Comment: sure, i don't know how to set username. please help

Comment: thanks chris, that my bad. that username should be 'root' no 'forge'

Answer (score 0):

Edit your config file in `app/config/local/database.php` instead. Or in the config file you have specified the database `laravel_crud`. Do a search for it if you can't find it.